# How do I determine if "DirectoryEntry" found my user?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I am using this simple method of finding a user in the current domain, that works for all users that 'exist' but I can't find any way to determine if the user does not exist.

```
string userLDAP = @"MYDOMAIN/username";
string path = "WinNT://" + userLDAP ;
DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry(path, null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
```

Other than letting an exception be thrown, how can I use a directory entry to determine if a user does not exist?

```
 if (root.Properties != null)
      if (root.Properties["objectSid"] != null)  //// EXCEPTION HERE
          if (root.Properties["objectSid"][0] != null)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's better to use DirectorySearcher for this purpose...

```
 string userName = "TargetUserName";

        using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher("GC://yourdomain.com"))
        {
            searcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={0}))", userName);

            using (SearchResultCollection results = searcher.FindAll())
            {
                if (results.Count > 0)
                  Debug.WriteLine("Found User");

            }
        }
```

This sample will search and entire forest including child domains.  If you want to target only a single domain use "LDAP://mydomain.com" instead of "GC://mydomain.com".  You can also supply searcher.SearchRoot with a DirectoryEntry to use as the root of a search (i.e. a specific OU or domain).

Don't forget most of the AD stuff is IDisposable so dispose properly as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

I think an easy way to check if your **DirectoryEntry** object points to an existing AD entry is using the static **Exists** method.

So your code may look like this:

```
using(DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(....)) {
   // now we check if the related object exists
   bool exists = DirectoryEntry.Exists(de.Path);
   if(exists) {
     // yes  the objects exists
     // do something

   } // end if
} // end using
```

Of course you can omit the exists variable. I used it just to make the statement more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a specific user, or all users?

I have an application that checks if a user is present by checking the account name - it uses `SecurityIdentifier` in the `System.Security.Principal` namespace to check if the Sid is valid.

```
public bool AccountExists(string name)
        {
            bool SidExists = false;
            try
            {
                NTAccount Acct = new NTAccount(name);
                SecurityIdentifier id = (SecurityIdentifier)Acct.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
                SidExists = id.IsAccountSid();
            }
            catch (IdentityNotMappedException)
            {
                //Oh snap.
            }
            return SidExists;
        }
```

You can specify the Domain when creating your `NTAccount` object

```
NTAccount Acct = new NTAccount("SampleDomain", "SampleName");
```

**EDIT**

In reference to your comment, would this work for you?  Didnt check it, might have to handle a possible null return before evaulating the `IsAccountSid()` method...

```
public SecurityIdentifier AccountSID(string myDomain, string myAcct)
{
   SecurityIdentifier id;

   try
   {
     NTAccount Acct = new NTAccount(myDomain, myAcct);
     id = (SecurityIdentifier)Acct.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
   }
   catch (IdentityNotMappedException)
   {
     //Oh snap.
   }

   return id;
}

SecurityIdentifier AcctSID = AccountSID("ExampleDomain", "ExampleName");

if (AcctSID.IsAccountSid())
   //Do Something
```

Comment: I'm looking for a specific user.  My goal is to get a SID for the purpose of adding it to a SSAS role

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question on [how to check if Windows user account name exists in domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329833/how-to-check-if-windows-user-account-name-exists-in-domain) may be helpful to you.