# How can my c# program detect whether it's plugged into the users home domain?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, network-programming, dns

The users of my application run the application on Laptops and I need the app settings to change based on the location of the currently logged in user. I want the app to use one group of settings when they are plugged into their HQ domain and different settings when they are out roaming away from the office.

How can I programmatically detect this?

Comment: What would you use to detect this non-programmatically? That is, suppose you were sat at the computer - which settings would you examine to determine your location (looking around is cheating!)

Comment: you would need a data connection

Comment: @AakashM How about computer, properties, workgroup / domain? Or Network and Sharing centre, currently connected to networks?

Comment: @Rup right, so if that's correct we now know the *actual* question: "how do I programmatically determine the workgroup / domain and/or currently connected networks?".

Answer (score 0):

You can send query into ActiveDirectory, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329833/how-to-check-if-windows-user-account-name-exists-in-domain), with current user name

```
IPrincipal threadPrincipal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
threadPrincipal.Identity.Name
```

Comment: When I am roaming, (unplug computer from network, go home) my username stays the same.

Comment: Yes, but in roaming AD service not available and DirectorySearcher  throws exception.